# Cursor SQLITE pegando o ultimo valor

Tags: android, sqlite

Como fazer com que o Cursor do SQLITE, faça com que as váriaveis não parem no ultimo valor ? Fiz um SetAdapter ao qual ele me lista todos os dados da ListView, até ai tudo bem, porém quando eu coloco alguma váriavel que fica dentro do WHILE, ele printa o ultimo valor, e eu preciso que ele me mostre todos os valores no Log.i(); Abaixo o código:

```
//Classe do select do SQLITE

public class Testesqlite extends Tela{

    static String testenome,testesobrenome,testenascimento;

    public void gambi(){

        Cursor c = bancosqlite.rawQuery("SELECT nome,sobrenome,nascimento FROM tabelateste",null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            testenome = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).trim();
             testesobrenome = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sobrenome")).trim();
             testenascimento = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nascimento")).trim();

        }
    }
}

  //Ação ao clicar em um item do ListView
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posicao, long id) {
            posi = parent.getItemAtPosition(posicao).toString();
                Testesqlite gambb = new Testesqlite();
            gambb.gambi();

                if (posi.equals(testenome)) {

                    Intent teste = new Intent(Testing.this, Tela_teste.class);
                    startActivity(teste);

                }
                 //Aqui ele me mostra corretamente a posição
                 //do item clicado, só que o da váriavel "testenome" que
                 //fica dentro do while fica só no
                 //no ultimo, fica toda hora printando o ultimo
                 //e não outros valores ; / 
                Log.i("Clicado", posi + "\t" + testenome);
            }

    });

}
```

O primeiro nome é o da váriavel "posi" e o segundo é o do "testenome" ao qual me mostra sempre o ultimo valor, não sei por que .

OBS: Ao clicar no item da ListView contendo o nome "Testeaaa" , ele abre outra activity sem problemas, porém outros não faz nada .

Mensagem no logcat

> 12-08 12:18:24.680  26825-26825/br.com.kappauni.teste I/Clicado﹕ Diego Kappaun Testeaaa
>   12-08 12:18:29.960  26825-26825/br.com.kappauni.teste I/Clicado﹕ Diella heckler granella    Testeaaa
>   12-08 12:18:38.960  26825-26825/br.com.kappauni.teste I/Clicado﹕ Testeaaa Testeaaa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O *while* percorre todo o cursor, do primeiro registo até ao último, atribuindo os valores dos campos sempre às mesmas variáveis. Portanto as variáveis terão o valor do último registo. Para poder ajudar necessitamos de saber qual é o propósito do seu código.

Comment: Preciso que quando clique em qualquer um dos nomes, ele recupere o valor do banco do que foi clicado . Quando clico no meu nome e no da minha namorada ele não funciona, só que quando clico em "Testeaaa" ele abre a tela normalmente, preciso apenas fazer com que isso funcione para dar continuidade no projeto. Editei a postagem e coloquei 2 imagens para visualização e desculpe pela má edição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há várias formas de obter os valores da linha clicada de uma `listView`, uma delas é através da `view` que é passada em `onItemClick`:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posicao, long id) {

        //Substitua R.id.TextViewNome pelo id da textView que recebe o campo "nome"
        TextView tvNome = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNome);
        Log.i("Clicado", posi + "\t" + tvNome.getText.toString());
    }
 }
```

Outra é ler diretamente do banco utilizando o `id` que é passada em `onItemClick`:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posicao, long id) {

        Cursor c = bancosqlite.rawQuery(
              "SELECT nome,sobrenome,nascimento
               FROM tabelateste 
               WHERE id = ?",new String[] {Long.toString(id)});

        //Se o seu adapter for do tipo cursorAdapter a linha anterior pode ser
        //substituida por:
        //Cursor c = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String testeNome = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).trim();
        String testeSobrenome = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sobrenome")).trim();
        String testeNascimento = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nascimento")).trim();

        Log.i("Clicado", posi + "\t" + testeNome);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Teria como dar um exemplo utilizando listview ?

Comment: ??? O exemplo que dei é utilizando listView.

Comment: Me referia ali no lugar de "TextView tvNome = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNome);". Obrigado pela resposta, assim que eu chegar em casa irei tentar implementar essa segunda opção e darei uma posição .

Comment: O primeiro método parte do principio que você tem uma *view* sua para os itens da *listView*. Se você está a usar a *view* `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` use `(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);` ou então use o segundo método.

Comment: Com a sua resposta deu para abrir um pouco mais a mente e usei comparações pra ver se determinado item era clicado para editar os campos separado . Darei como resolvido . Obrigado .